# How to Access Map Value In Thymeleaf Directly By its Key

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

**In Java Controller**

```
Map<Integer, String> student = new HashMap<>();
student.put(1,"Kiran");

String rollno= 1;

model.addAttribute("student", student);
model.addAttribute("rollNo", rollno);
```

**In Thyme leaf**

```
<span th:text="'${topMap.get(1)}"></span>
```

**Above line is working fine but, instead of 1 I want to pass rollno variable which is passed through model to UI page**

**for example, I am expecting something like follows**

```
 <span th:text="'${student.get('${rollno}')}"></span>
```

**None of this solution is working**

```
<span th:text="'${student.get(${rollno})}"></span>
<span th:text="'${student.get(rollno)}"></span>
<span th:text="'${student[rollno]}"></span>
<span th:text="'${student[${rollno}]}"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if this works for you:

```
${student[__${rollno}__]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just converted it to map key into string, and it worked fine for me

for ex-

```
Integer a = 1;
Map<String, String> student = new HashMap<>();
student.put(a.toString(),"Kiran");
```